# Maven: liquibase - firebird: Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error

Tags: maven, firebird, liquibase

I'm able to use `mvn liquibase:update` to execute .sql queries against my Firebird db.

This works:

```
CREATE TABLE xxx (
  xxx
);
```

But when I execute this command in the .sql it fails (X represents length, I saw this would be too long for MySQL but it's Firebird):

```
GRANT SELECT ON XXXX_XXXXXX TO XXXXX_XXXX_XXXXX_XXXX;
```

Error:

```
[ERROR]      Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error
[ERROR] SQL error code = -104
[ERROR] Token unknown - line 8, column 1
[ERROR] GRANT [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE XXXX_XXXX(
```

The line in the error is the line of my GRANT command. When I remove that command from the script (only execute the CREATE TABLE) it works. What am I doing wrong?

Executing the command manually works.

**Update:**
It seems that the setup works when I add the create table statement in 0001.sql and the Grant command in 0002.sql.

My .sql file looks like this (my firebird config is default after the install of 2.5.8):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_GAMES (
  TEST_GAME_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  MONO_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PERIOD_FROM TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PERIOD_TO TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
GRANT SELECT ON TEST_GAMES TO GAME_TEST_GAME_READ;
```

`GAME_TEST_GAME_READ` is made during the DB setup:

```
CREATE DATABASE 'C:/firebird/TEST_GAME.fdb' USER 'TEST_GAME' PASSWORD 'TEST_GAME';
CONNECT 'C:/firebird/TEST_GAME.fdb' USER 'TEST_GAME' PASSWORD 'TEST_GAME';

CREATE ROLE GAME_TEST_GAME_READ;
CREATE ROLE GAME_TEST_GAME_WRITE;
```

Liquibaseconfig:

```
<properties>
    <liquibase.plugin.version>3.5.3</liquibase.plugin.version>
    <firebird.client.version>2.1.6</firebird.client.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>liquibase/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                <changeLogFile>liquibase/db-changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
            </configuration>
```

The changelog master contains a section /scripts which are executed

property file:

```
# Firebird
driver=org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
url=jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/C:/firebird/GAME_TEST_GAME.fdb
username=GAME_TEST_GAME
password=GAME_TEST_GAME
```

**Update2:**

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">
    <include file="liquibase/db-changelog-1.0.xml"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

and changelog1:

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <includeAll path="01-testgame-scripts/" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <changeSet id="tag-1.0" author="myname">
        <tagDatabase tag="1.0" />
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

and inside `01-testgame-scripts` I have the `.sql` file.

Comment: The error seems to indicate it is executing multiple statements at once (given the 'line 8' and the unknown token is `GRANT`, and the fact the 'Failed SQL' reported by Liquibase starts with `CREATE TABLE` and not with `GRANT`), statements must be executed individually. Please show the full contents of your `.sql` file and the configuration of Liquibase.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Hmm you're right. When I create 2 seperate .sql files it works (first create the table), next the grant. I've updated my question with my.sql file.

Comment: And what is the liquibase configuration?

Comment: I've edit the config

Comment: It would be more helpful to have [mcve], but I'll see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: Does liquibase - in general or when applied to firebird - allow or prohibit having multiple statements in one SQL file ?

Comment: @Arioch'The It allows it, and it should split, assuming the correct coverntions are applied and the defaults are not overridden. I haven't used liquibase in a while, but it looks like the OP is using liquibase in a wrong way here.

Comment: Could you post the content of your `db-changelog-master.xml` as well?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'll check the url. I've added my .xml files.

Comment: I tried to update to firebird client 3.0.4 (I'm using jdk8) and liquibase plugin version 3.6.2 but same issue

Comment: It has indeed nothing to do with GRANT itself. If I put another statement (just a select, behind it I have the same error on select).

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this, but I run into issues with the inclusion of files, all I get are "Cannot find base path" errors as soon as I try to include anything.

Comment: I can tell you I used this tutorial http://shengwangi.blogspot.com/2016/04/liquibase-helloworld-example.html but using firebird instead of mysql and my own .sql's of course

Comment: Ah found the problem, the method described in that tutorial won't work with Maven like that, because it doesn't process the resources. Managed to reproduce it.

Comment: I'm looking here now: https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql_file.html This seems to help..

Comment: @mealesbia That is an alternative, but as you see in my answer, you can do it with only SQL files, provided they are correctly commented as expected by Liquibase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your SQL files do not follow the requirements for [Liquibase SQL changelog files](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html), as a result they are just sent as is without any parsing or interpretation (ie splitting separate statements). Firebird nor Jaybird supports executing multiple statements in one execute.

It will work correctly if you change the SQL file to

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset mealesbia:1
CREATE TABLE TEST_GAMES (
  TEST_GAME_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  MONO_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PERIOD_FROM TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PERIOD_TO TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
GRANT SELECT ON TEST_GAMES TO GAME_TEST_GAME_READ;
```

The marking with `--liquibase formatted sql` will cause Liquibase to parse the SQL file and create change sets from it (marked with `--changeset author:id attribute1:value1 attribute2:value2 [...]`, here I used `--changeset mealesbia:1`. This parsing includes splitting the statements for individual execution (unless overridden with explicit attributes).

As an alternative, you can also include your SQL files explicitly in your XML using [`sqlFile`](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql_file.html). This requires explicitly defining the change set in the XML and linking the associated SQL script (whereas the previous solution will define the change set together with the SQL within the SQL file).

Comment: Thanks, I'm now trying to use the sqlFile. it works when I explicitly define the .sql file. Do you know if I can define the directory only (without specifying every file?)

Comment: @mealesbia You can, if you use the comment markers to define change sets as I suggest in the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use GRANT definition described in [Firebird documentation](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-security-grant-revoke.html)

```
GRANT
   {<privileges> ON <object> | role}
   TO <grantees>
   [WITH {GRANT|ADMIN} OPTION]
   [{GRANTED BY | AS} [USER] grantor]
```

Than your code would look like this:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE XXXX_XXXXXX TO USER XXXXX_XXXX_XXXXX_XXXX;
```

[Another useful documentation link](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-security-privs.html)

Comment: For `table` the object type is optional. As shown by the syntax on the page you link to: `GRANT <privileges> ON [TABLE] {tablename | viewname}`. If this would have been the cause, it would have yielded a _token unknown XXXX_XXXXXX_ instead of _token unknown GRANT_.

Comment: BTW: Your first link is to the language reference update, which only documents **changes** since InterBase 6.0. The second is to the Firebird Language Reference which replaces the InterBase 6 + language reference updates.

Comment: No, it is not the syntax error in GRANT here, the error text - `GRANT [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE XXXX_XXXX` - hints clearly that the client library fails to parse the script into different statements. Maybe it was not supposed to and its scripts must be one statement per file, dunno. I remember I had a similar issue with UIB Delphi lib, where I had to fix the sources to let the scripter understand some new FB2.1 command thus to split statements.